# Closest alphabetical match in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of company names, e.g:

```
Apple
IBM
Microsoft
Xerox
```

I also have a string, and I want to find the closest entry in the list, alphabetically, after the place the string would be (it isn't necessarily in the list, although it might be), or the last entry in the list if the string is alphabetically greater than the last entry.

```
'AAA' would return 'Apple'
'IBM' would return 'IBM'
'Intel' would return 'Microsoft'
'ZZZ' would return 'Xerox'
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You'll need to also post what you've tried.

Comment: Loop and compare. Basically how any sorting algorithm works.

Comment: If list is sorted, look for binary search

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work, item has to be larger than previous item/undefined and less than or equal to current item, otherwise last item in the sorted array

```
var arr = ['Apple', 'IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Xerox'].sort();
var match = (str) => arr.find((item, index) => {
    return (
        str.toLowerCase() > (arr[index - 1] || '').toLowerCase() &&
        str.toLowerCase() <= item.toLowerCase()
    );
}) || arr[arr.length - 1];

console.log(match('AAA')); // "Apple"
console.log(match('IBM')); // "IBM"
console.log(match('Intel')); // "Microsoft"
console.log(match('ZZZ')); // "Xerox"
```